# Is there a way to provide customized sorting rules to "ls" command?

Tags: customization, ls, file-sorting

I work in material science so many of my directories are named by chemical element or equation. As such, `ls` and `ls -v` list my directories out of chemical order. I know I could rename my directories so they start with the atomic number of the element, but I don't want to do that. I was wondering if there was a simple way I could provide customized rules to `ls` such that it would list the directories according to the atomic number of the element instead of alphabetic or numeric order. If there was an alternative to `ls` that would be acceptable too.

Comment: You can use the `-U` argument to prevent sorting by `ls`, in which case the files are listed in the order in which they are passed as arguments. Then you can wrap the call to `ls`in a script that pre-sorts the files to your liking.

Comment: You could prefix your filenames with a "sorting number", e.g.  `0001_Hydrogen`, `0142_Unobtanium`, or you could use the `stat` call to write a script. See `man stat`.

Comment: ...which he stated very clearly that he didn't want to do. So that cannot be The Solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Make some test dirs:

```
cd /tmp
for atom in H He Li Be B C N O F Ne Na;do mkdir $atom-directory;done
```

The atomic number for each symbol:

```
export ATOMS="H 1 He 2 Li 3 Be 4 B 5 C 6 N 7 O 8 F 9 Ne 10 Na 11" #and so on...
```

Make a bash function, make sure everything is on one line:

```
atomls () { for f in $(perl -le'%m=split" ",$ENV{ATOMS};$re=join"|",keys%m;print for map$$_[0],sort{$m{$$a[1]}<=>$m{$$b[1]}}map[$_,/($re)\b/],@ARGV' $*);do ls -ld $f; done }
```

Run it:

```
atomls *
```

Result:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 H-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 He-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 Li-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 Be-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 B-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 C-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 N-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 O-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 F-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 Ne-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 Na-directory
```

List just the two letter atoms:

```
atomls ??-dir*
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 He-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 Li-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 Be-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 Ne-directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 idiot idiot 4096 okt.  22 19:56 Na-directory
```

There might be better ways...